# Is there documentation for implementing the server portion of Socket.IO?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, long-polling, server-push

I don't want to use the NodeJS server implementation. What protocols do I need my server implementation to support? Where can I find the technical details?

Comment: So you're implementing ________ using the _________ programming language, and your application is _____________ , and you need to _____________ to clients.  Makes sense. Let me think for a sec ...

Comment: @Pointy, he's asking for the protocol used by the Socket.IO implementation.  It seems like a reasonable question, even though Socket.IO is not standardized.  I don't have to ask what language someone is using before explaining the HTTP protocol.

Comment: @Mathew Flaschen well perhaps that's true, and if so there are some non-Node server-side projects listed on the [Socket.IO home page](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 2):

[Use the source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node/blob/master/support/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js). The client library will try these transports in the specified order:

```
transports: ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 
             'xhr-multipart', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'],
```

It will invoke the `.check()` method on each of them, which determines browser capabilities, and uses the first one that matches. On connect, it will then keep trying other transports until it finds one that actually connects. Using the `options` field, the application can customize this selection process as it pleases.